# CG shader threshold function

Tags: shader, fragment-shader, cg, threshold

Is there some builtin fragment function in CG that allows me to compute the following without conditionals?

y = x>bias?1.0f:0.0f;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.  It's a **>=** instead of a **>**

http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/step.html

y = step(bias, x);